# Configuring Magento 2.3 MSI (Multi Source Inventory) with Multiple Stocks

Tags: magento2.3, multi-source-inventory, manage-stock

I am trying to configure Magento MSI with Multiple Stock for a single Sales Channel but it only allows me to assign single stock to a sales channel. Based on Magento's documentation, this is how it is expected to work. Is there a way I can modify this behavior to have multiple stocks assigned to a single sales channel?

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/inventory-stock.html

Below is my scenario. I have three Vendors and each has its own warehouse. At a time, it only allows assigning Sales Channel to just one stock which is below screenshot is Vendor 1.

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible in MSI. You can assign a single stock to a website only. Let me ask why do you need this? You can create a single stock and assign all sources to it. You'll assign a concrete source (and therefore a vendor) on the create shipment stage.